# How to return a list from an IF statement in R?

Tags: r

How do I return a list from the calculated results? The list must be the same length as the first argument.

```
circlecalc <- function(var1,R){
  if (is.numeric(R) && min(R) >=1){
  (toupper(var1)=='AC')
    pi*R^2
  } else if (toupper(var1)=='CC') {
    2*pi*R 
  } else if (toupper(var1)=='VS') {
    4/3*pi*R^3
  } else if (toupper(var1)=='AS') {
    4*pi*R^2
  } else stop ("not valid")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your current approach is that regular `if` and `else` are not vectorized.  You may try using `case_when` from the `dplyr` package, which is vectorized.

```
library(dplyr)

circlecalc <- case_when(
    is.numeric(R) && min(R) >= 1 && toupper(var1) == 'AC' ~ pi*R^2,
    toupper(var1) == 'CC' ~ 2*pi*R,
    toupper(var1) == 'VS' ~ 4/3*pi*R^3,
    toupper(var1) == 'AS' ~ 4*pi*R^2,
    TRUE ~ "not valid"
)
```